# How can an ES6 module be run as a script in Node?

Tags: node.js, executable, es6-modules, shebang

How can an ES6 module be run as a script in Node?

When I try this shebang I get an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --experimental-modules
```

> /usr/bin/env: ‘node --experimental-modules’: No such file or directory

If I use this shebang it has syntax errors (of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

The work around I'm using is to use a shell script to call the module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

BASEDIR=$( dirname "$0" )
node --experimental-modules $BASEDIR/script.mjs "$@"
```

Is it possible to get this working without a second file?

Comment: What version of node are you using? Apart from a couple of rarely used features, and apart from tail call recursion, node.js has almost full support of ES6 by default since July 2017. The easiest solution is probably to upgrade node.js. I personally use the `n` package (`npm install -g n` then `n stable`)

Comment: @slebetman You must still pass the --experimental-modules flag. They're anticipating this will be enabled by default only in Node v10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly when it changed, but in recent Node versions no special care is needed, if the script is part of a package (ie, there is a package.json file in the folder or any parent folder). Just ensure these steps are followed:

1. In package.json, set `"type": "module"`
2. Give the file a `.js` extension
3. Use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Answer (score 15):

I've patched [Ishan Thilina Somasiri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179910/791414) solution to work with `Node 13` without the `.mjs` extension:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env bash
":" //# comment; exec /usr/bin/env node --input-type=module - "$@" < "$0"

import { hostname } from 'os';

console.log(hostname());
```

The trick is pretty much the same, but using stdin, which is the only [documented](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) way when you don't have a `package.json` nor the `.mjs` extension. Thus, a standalone extensionless script.

**However**, global variables like `__dirname` or `__filename` won't be available.

Comment: Thanks! I also managed to get around the `__dirname` issue using `process.cwd()`

Comment: CWD is very different from __dirname, the latter is supposed to be the location of the script while the former is supposed to represent your current execution directory. This is: if you execute the script from the folder on which the script is in, then both will be the same, however, if you go one directory up and execute the script from that directory, then they will differ

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass the argument to node on shebang. This is explained very well in the article at http://sambal.org/2014/02/passing-options-node-shebang-line/.

The code will be as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh 
":" //# comment; exec /usr/bin/env node --harmony "$0" "$@"

console.log("It Works!");
```

I used `harmony` instead of `--experimental-modules`. The explanation from the web site is follows.

> The #!/bin/sh causes the script to be identified as a shell script,
>   and passed to /bin/sh for execution. /bin/sh reads and executes
>   scripts one line at a time, and we’re taking advantage of that below.
>
> The second line, as interpreted by the shell, consists of two
>   commands.
>
> - 2a. The first command is ":", which is the quoted version of the
>     rarely-used bash command :, which means “expand arguments and no-op”.
>     The only argument to : is //, which is a valid path. The following #
>     is a bash comment, which is valid until the command separator ;.
> - 2b. The second command is exec /usr/bin/env node --noharmony "$0"
>     "$@"
>     which executes the node interpreter with the desired arguments and
>     passes argument 0 (this script file) and the rest of the arguments to
>     the bash script ("$@")
>
> The exec causes the bash process to be replaced by the node process,
>   so bash does not attempt to process any further lines.

Comment: This is also great because even though that line never gets run by JavaScript, the syntax is valid. `//` makes it work.