# How to execute node.js file with Powershell without `node` before the name?

Tags: node.js, powershell, powershell-core

Is there a way to execute node.js files from Powershell without calling the file with `node` before the file name?

Example:

Now I'm executing it like this: `node .\script.mjs`.

I would like to execute it with the name only: `.\script.mjs`.

How to?

Comment: What would be the expected output? Is `script.mjs` executable?

Comment: Now I'm executing it with `node` word before. I would like to call it directly in PowerShell like in bash.

Comment: I don't know if I can help you since I'm not familiar with bash. I assume that under the hood, you still call it `node .\script.mjs` because if the file is not executable, what should happen? Probably on your linux environment you have something configured (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179714/how-can-an-es6-module-be-run-as-a-script-in-node)) that allows you to do that. I don't know if you can make PS do something like "this is a `*.mjs` file, execute it with `node`". I still don't see the issue with `node .\script.mjs`.

Comment: @Vivere, too long to write day-by-day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register the `.mjs` file extension to be opened with `node.exe` by default. Then you can call node by just providing a path to a `.mjs` file. Steps:

1. Right click any `.mjs` file
2. Click on *Open with* / *Open with...*
3. Click on *Choose another app* / *More apps ↓ > Look for another app on this PC*
4. Navigate to your `node.exe` file
5. Tick the *Always use this app to open .mjs files* checkbox
6. Confirm with *OK*

Now you can just enter `.\script.mjs` in CMD or PowerShell to automatically open the file with node.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @tackprotector you can do the same thing using the `cmd.exe` command line with the two following tools :

[Assoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770920(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) displays or modifies file name extension associations. If used without parameters, assoc displays a list of all the current file name extension associations. If you type `assoc .txt` it returns `.txt=txtfile`.

[Ftype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771394(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) displays or modifies file types that are used in file name extension associations. If used without an assignment operator (=), ftype displays the current open command string for the specified file type. If used without parameters, ftype displays the file types that have open command strings defined. If you type `ftype textfile` it returns `textfile="%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\WORDPAD.EXE" "%1"`

So if I type `assoc .mjs` it returns that nothing is associeted with `.mjs`

So I type (in a cmd. as admin) :

```
assoc .mjs=nodejsfile
ftype nodejsfile=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1
```

The first time I invoke a `.mjs` file it will ask me if I want to use notepad++ to open it, after that the association is done. You can do the same with `node.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an executable from that file using [vercel/pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg), then can run `pkg .\script.mjs -t win` to create an exe file using pkg