# Execute python without using the path variable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

Is there a way to execute a python script in PowerShell without using: python myfile.py

I want to execute it without using the word python

I am trying to execute the python script located in EC2 windows via SSM and Lambda. Python is not getting recognized so is there any way to execute the file without using the word python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just associate the `.py` file ending with your `python` executable. I posted detailed steps for it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466563/11942268).

Comment: How to do it in boto3?    
 response = ssm_client.send_command(
                InstanceIds=['i-*********'],
                DocumentName="AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
              #  Parameters={'commands': [f'[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable({a}, {b})']}, )
                Parameters={'commands': [f'env:Path = {path1}']}, )

Like what to keep in the commands?

Comment: @SairamRavuri You have to make this change in the Windows OS that hosts the PowerShell with which you want to execute your python script.